# Create woocommerce order on new user registration

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

The goal is to create a new order when a new user registers *wordpress* site. 
To achieve that, the following hook was added to child theme's *functions.php*.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_order', 10, 1 );

    function add_order( $user_id ) {

        $order = wc_create_order();
        $order->set_customer_id($user_id);
        $order->save();
    }
```

However, when a new user registers, no new order is created. No error is seen in the log.
Wondering how to achieve the goal correctly.

Comment: Please check your child theme is Working or not because your code is testing in my site it's working when reg. user get order in backed.

Comment: hi, thanks. it's created in db, but not displayed in wp-admin->woocommerce->orders